# 2008 BMW 328i: Engine ticking & sounding like it wants to stall

Tags: bmw, stall

So i'm stumped. Car is running very rough at idle, ticking noise and it wants to stall.

- I've replaced Spark Plugs \ Ignition coils
- DISA valve exploded, passed through intake. Replaced disa valve, recovered broken pieces of flap.
- Oil changed as well

Car : 2008 BMW 328i

Mileage: 155k

UPDATE:

DISA valve self-destructed and sent two pieces of flap through the intake manifold and landed on the top of the valves. Nothing got through the valves and was able to recover both complete pieces of flap and metal pin. DISA was replaced & car still rough running. Possible this damaged the valves? Any way to verify this?

Compression Test Results

Cylinder 1 - 190

Cylinder 2 - 190

Cylinder 3 - 160

Cylinder 4 - 190

Cylinder 5 - 0

Cylinder 6 - 170

Broken Flap

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmFO9.jpg

Below is a video of the engine running

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6_iup0fJ18&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a great question  :) Do you have any fault codes?

Comment: Managed to pull the codes, currently receiving the following:


1. DME: Combustion misfires, Cylinder 3
2. DME: Combustion misfires, Cylinder 4
3. DME: Combustion misfires, Cylinder 5
4. DME: Combustion misfires, Cylinder 6
5. DME: Combustion misfires, Several Cylinders

Answer (score 0):

As George suggested, check for fault codes if you can.

In my own opinion, this noise could sound like hydraulic followers ticking or another camshaft related component noise, but to be sure, you could use a strobe light synchronized with your engine, to identify the frequency of the noise, if it happens at every revolution, it's probably a crankshaft related noise, if it happens every two revolutions of the cranckshaft, it's probably a camshaft related noise.

If you don't have such tools (I do not have such tools), you could drive the car downhill (if there are hills around you, else try on the flat) engine braking, or shutting  the engine off, just to see if it stops when there is no explosion, if it stops, the noise probably come from a crankshaft related component (crankshaft bearings, connecting rod bearings, piston pins)... (I hope it doesn't), it could mean there is clearance between some crankshaft or pistons related components and the explosion in the cylinder pushes one of these components against the other because of this clearance, making a knocking sound.

If you can still hear the noise without explosion, it's certainly caused by the camshafts or the valvetrains, it could be failing followers (I assume yours are hydraulic), or bent valves that are not closing correctly for instance, increasing the valve clearance and making the cams knock.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm thinking its possible the valves bent. The DISA valve on the outside of the intake manifold self destructed and sent 2 pieces of flap through the intake manifold and into the valves. Nothing got passed the valves and I was able to recover all the pieces of the broken flap and metal pin. How would i be able to verify bent valves or not?

Image of broken flap
https://i.imgur.com/7kKR3TWl.jpg

Comment: If you have a mechanic stethoscope (if you don't, a long screwdriver will do the job), you can place the metal end on different points of the engine and listen to where the noise sounds the loudest (with the screwdriver, just put your ear on the other end). If it seems to come from the head, I would remove the head cover and gently try to push the valve followers down when the cams are up (you can turn the crankshaft by hand with a wrench to rotate the camshafts). If a follower is  floating, even slightly, there something wrong with this valvetrain. You could also check the valve clearance.

Comment: If you own a compressiometer, you could perform a compression test for each cylider (I should have told you that before to remove the head cover), a loss of compression in one or more cylinder would indicate that their not correctly sealed. If you really think that some head components are the culprits, and you're at ease with head removal, you can remove the head to check them directly.

Comment: Managed to check the compression, not good. Cylinder 1 - 190 Cylinder 2 - 190 Cylinder 3 - 160 Cylinder 4 - 190 Cylinder 5 - 0 Cylinder 6 - 170

Comment: Yes, cylinder 5 is leaking, this may explain why your engine wants to stall, and why you've got some misfires in it. This leakage could the result of one or more bent valves in cylinder 5. Do you plan to fix it yourself, or to have it done for you ?

Comment: Will have to pull the head first to make my assessment. But i'm thinking of doing it on my own, a few friends and some cold brewski's should help! Would you say Cylinder 3 & 6 are damaged as well? Compression results on them are a little low compared to the rest.

Comment: You could try to perform a wet compression test (just pour some oil in the cylinder before testing it). The oil will seal the piston rings, as your engine is old, they may be a little worn out, but such values are not so bad and seem okay to me.

Comment: Before you remove the head, have you already done it ? If not I would advise you to take the time to look for some specific documentation about your engine. Some friends help would indeed be welcome, the head is heavy and some parts might need more than two hands to be removed. Be careful not to scratch or damage parts. Take a large piece of cardboard to stick the bolts through it, and stick papers to wires, to know what goes where when you'll put everything back together. And once you'll have the head stripped, waiting for the parts you ordered, consider have the ports ported and polished :)

Comment: So i was rechecking the intake ports again right before i took off the head. Took off the intake manifold and checked all the intake valves. Managed to find another small piece of the flap stuck in cylinder 5. Took it out. Will Put the valve cover back on tomorrow and run another compression test. Hopefully this is what is causing the no compression. Fingers Crossed!

Comment: Retested cylinder 5. 100 PSI significantly better than 0. Will be taking off the head later next week.

Comment: So i've recharged the battery as i felt it was a little low. Retested cylinder 5 it is now at 210 PSI so all seems good. Ran the car for a bit and the engine still has a slight misfire / surge but no noise as before. Could possibly be a vacuum leak somewhere as i do hear air escaping from somewhere.

Comment: Nice to hear it runs better now, check your intake for leaks (maybe it's not well tightened), and pay attention to your engine's noises and behaviour for some time, because the piece of flap may have damage something, be careful about that misfire you mentionned, as it also may cause damage.